# how to pass json response from one html page to another html page using angularJs?

Tags: json, angularjs

I have api for search functionality which has written in **Laravel PHP**.When I type some string in input tag and click on search button, then I am geeting the json response.

Now what I have to do is on ngClick a new html page should open say "search.html" with display the json response using angularjs.

I am not able to do, may be my lake of knowledge:). Can anybody tell me how can I do this.

Here is my code:

```
// Search Controller

QAApp.controller('SearchCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.search = function (searchtag) {
           var request = $http({
                          method: 'GET', 
                          url: server + 'api/question/tagged/' + searchtag,
                        });
                request.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.qa = data;
            });

        }

  });
```

html page is :

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" ng-controller = "SearchCtrl">
                        <div style = "float: right; margin-top: 7px;" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...." name = "tag"  ng-model = "tag">
                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click = "search(tag);">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Comment: you have any code to open the page?

Comment: I have created a html page and on click that json response display in that html page. I have created a html page only.

Comment: If you know how can I  do this please tell me........

Comment: U want one html response to another html...is it a spa or totally different pages...i mean are these templates or pages?

Comment: this is totally different page........my search UI is on one html page and after click on search button,  get the json response and I have to show on another page.So, on click two event happen one is get response and another is display it on another html page. So,both event happen together get and display the data..........

Comment: then you can do this using browser localStorage

Comment: Can I save that json response in a variable and use that variable in html page using angularjs.......if you have any idea please tell me.....

Comment: yes thats what localStorage is for....let me jot an answer using the same that any1 can use for this kind of problem

Comment: You can use the local storage , But with angularjs you dont want to load the html again. You can just download the different template and show it.  if you want I can show that in my answer

Comment: please show the example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over here you have two different pages and whenever you are moving from one page to other (no SPA) the page will complete refresh....so if one is thinking of having it in global variables, services or even $rootScope that will not work as these variables will get refreshed.

In order to cope up then we either need to work with cookies, querystring or the browser localStorage.

In order to use local Storage in Angularjs you need to include a script in both the pages for angular-local-storage [Github Link](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Code Example how to use it:

```
angular.module('yourModule', ['LocalStorageModule'])
.controller('yourCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  'localStorageService',
  function($scope, localStorageService) {
    // Start fresh
    localStorageService.clearAll();

    // Set a key
    localStorageService.set('Favorite Sport','Ultimate Frisbee');

    // Delete a key
    localStorageService.delete('Favorite Sport');
}]);

/*
To set the prefix of your localStorage name, you can use the setPrefix method 
available on the localStorageServiceProvider
*/
angular.module('yourModule', ['LocalStorageModule'])
.config(['localStorageServiceProvider', function(localStorageServiceProvider){
  localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('newPrefix');
}]);
```

Library main functions:

1. .set : to set a key value in the localStorage space
2. .clearAll: clear all the keys in localStorage
3. .delete: delete a key
4. .get: get a key from localStorage

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agrublev/QjVq3/)

Reference of what [local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) is actually about

Comment: I am not able to do this, can you show me any example, I am new to angularjs and not understanding how can I do this.....

Comment: @AnitaMehta you can read on it over here http://amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/html5-local-storage-angular-js